# "Could not normalize path file" while trying to uploading library to maven

Tags: java, android, maven

I was following the steps from [here](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/how-to-upload-library-to-jcenter-maven-central-as-dependency/en). I stuck at part 5. It gives an error like this when I run the command "> gradlew install".

> - What went wrong: Failed to capture snapshot of ²nput files for task 'javadoc' property 'classpath' during up-to-date check.
>
>   > Could not normalize path for file 'C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\android.jar;C:\Users\Lenovo\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-26\optional\org.apache.http.legacy.jar'.

Also the install command runs this [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/installv1.gradle) and there is another command called [bintray](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nuuneoi/JCenter/master/bintrayv1.gradle) and it gives the same error.

If you have any ideas or find that the route I am following right now is not that good, I'm open to other ideas.

Comment: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/could-not-normalize-path-for-file-for-windows-classpath/7372/6

Comment: I think i need to put a separator like `compile files(myClasspath.split(";")) ` but I don't even know where does install file uses this directory.